# Mongo Text Search Multiple Phrases - AND, OR

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

The following returns all documents having both the phrases "Comp and Comp" AND "Low Threat"

```
{ $text: { $search: '"Comp and Comp" "Low Threat"' } }
```

Similary, how to make OR text search on multiple phrases ?

Nearest I was able to get is the following :

```
{ $text: { $search: 'Comp and Comp Low Threat' } }
```

But it doesn't have a way to group phrases and it does an OR only on individual strings.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, You have to execute two separate calls, due to the `$text` [restrictions](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#restrictions)

> A query can specify, at most, one $text expression.

> If the $search string includes a phrase and individual terms, text search will only match the documents that include the phrase.

Essentially two phrases execute `$and` logic between them, and because you can only execute a single `$text` query you need to split it into 2 calls.

Comment: Doesn't work. Looks like only one `$text` can appear in an `$or`. A `$text` operator can only occur once in the stage. I get 'Too many text expressions' error

Comment: True, literally the first restriction in the docs is: "A query can specify, at most, one $text expression". I edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for the problem (an *OR* search over a list of terms and **phrases**) in Python (PyMongo).

```
def search_phrases_or(terms, filter={}, projection={}):
    """
    Perform an OR search over a list of terms, which can be unigrams (single words) or phrases (multiple words),
    combining the results while avoiding duplicates.
    """
    if "_id" in projection:
        projection.pop("_id") # _id is needed by the method to detect duplicates
    
    # Split terms into unigrams and phrases
    unigrams = [term for term in terms if " " not in term]
    phrases = [term for term in terms if " " in term]

    results = []
    seen_ids = set()

    # Search for unigrams, if any
    if unigrams:
        unigram_search_string = " ".join(unigrams)
        unigram_results = beigebook_sentences_all.find({**{"$text": {"$search": unigram_search_string}}, **filter}, projection)
        results = list(unigram_results)
        seen_ids = {doc['_id'] for doc in results}
    
    # Search for each bigram and add new results
    for phrase in phrases:
        phrase_results = beigebook_sentences_all.find({**{"$text": {"$search": unigram_search_string}}, **filter}, projection)
        for doc in phrase_results:
            if doc['_id'] not in seen_ids:
                results.append(doc)
                seen_ids.add(doc['_id'])
    
    return results
```

Then calling `search_terms_or(myCollection, ["Comp and Comp", "Low Threat"])` would give you the desired result.